# python renaming multiple files

Tags: python

I want to rename all the files in a specific folder using python but getting this error while executing the code:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'D:\New folder\New Text Document.txt' -> 'D:\New folder\kj1.txt'

I am trying to rename all the files in the path: D:\New Folder\

```py
dname = input("\nenter the path\t")
if os.path.isdir(dname):
   dst = input("\nenter new file name: \t")
   for i in os.listdir(dname):
       n = 1
       mystr = ".txt"
       src = os.path.join(dname, i)
       dd = dst + str(n) + mystr
       dd = os.path.join(dname, dd)
       os.rename(src, dd)
       n = n + 5
   for i in os.listdir(dname):
       print(i)
```

Comment: Check if the file 'kj1.txt' already exists.

Comment: Move the `n = 1` out of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the destination file, *kj 1.txt* already exists. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename),

> On Windows, if `dst` already exists, `OSError` will be raised even if it is a file.

Comment: Hi. The destination file does not exit. in the for loop, the program renames the file to "kj1.txt". then , in the next iteration, the program throws error "destination file kj1.txt exists". Could you help me resolve this error.

Comment: That makes sense. The first time, the kj1 file did not exist. At the next iteration, the script still wanted to rename a file to kj1. This time, it exists.Throw n=1 out of the loop.